# How to refactor Java 7 as Java 8 when comparing a map and list

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, refactoring, java-stream

I'd like to refactor the following code make it more readable. Is there a way to make this more readable using streams and lambdas, or does it make sense to leave the code as is?

```
List<Data> data = ...;
Map<String, Task> tasks = ...;
for (Data datum : data) {
    String compKey = datum.getCompKey();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Task> taskEntry : tasks.entrySet()) {
        String taskKey = taskEntry.getKey();
        Task task = taskEntry.getValue();
        if (taskKey != null && task != null) {
            String subKey = Joiner.on(".").useForNull("null").join(Arrays.copyOfRange(taskKey.split("\\."), 0, 3));
            if (compKey.equals(subKey)) {
                task.setVal1(datum.getVal1());
                task.setVal2(datum.getVal2());
                task.setVal3(datum.getVal3());                       
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
tasks.forEach((key, task) -> {
    if (key != null && task != null) {
        key = String.join(".", Arrays.asList(key.split("\\.")).subList(0, 3));
        data.stream()
            .filter(d -> d.getCompKey().equals(key))
            .findAny()
            .ifPresent(d -> {
                task.setVal1(d.getVal1());
                task.setVal2(d.getVal2());
                task.setVal3(d.getVal3());
            });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't say this is any more readable than your code, but it goes to show that good ol' for-loops still suffice:

```
List<Data> data = ...;
Map<String, Task> tasks = ...;

UnaryOperator<String> function = s -> {
    return Joiner.on(".")
                 .useForNull("null")
                 .join(Arrays.copyOfRange(s.split("\\."), 0, 3));
};

data.forEach(datum -> {
    final String compKey = datum.getCompKey();

    tasks.entrySet()
         .stream()
         .filter(e -> e.getKey() != null && e.getValue() != null)
         .filter(e -> compKey.equals(function.apply(e.getKey())))
         .findFirst()
         .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
         .ifPresent(task -> {
             task.setVal1(datum.getVal1());
             task.setVal2(datum.getVal2());
             task.setVal3(datum.getVal3());
         });
});
```